# What am I doing wrong, I'm not sure how to fix my code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a maths quiz in python and while most of the code works  when I type in the correct answer the code always prints incorrect.

```
import random


Name=input("What is your name?")
Class=input("wWhat class are you in?")
print("Welcome" ,Name, "to the Maths Quiz!!")

QuestionNumber=0
Operations=["+","-","x"]

Num1=random.randint(1,30)
Num2=random.randint(1,30)     
answer=0

while QuestionNumber < 10:
    QuestionNumber=QuestionNumber+1
    print("What is", Num1 ,random.choice(Operations),Num2)
    guess=int(input("What is the answer to this question?"))

    if Operations=="+":
        answer=Num1+Num2

    elif Operations=="-":
            answer=Num1-Num2

    elif Operations=="x":
        answer=Num1*Num2

    if guess==answer:
        print ("Correct")

    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

Comment: `Operations` is still just a list, so you never update `answer = 0`. Add some `print`s to debug.

Comment: Do you really want `Num1` & `Num2` to have the same values for all 10 questions? If not, you need to put `Num1=random.randint(1,30)` and `Num2=random.randint(1,30)` inside your `while` loop.

Comment: Yes I realised that after I the code started to work , I already have changed it, Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if Operations=="+":`

you are comparing a List object with a string. That seems wrong. As jon mentions, this causes `answer` to always stay 0.

You should change to something like this

```
while QuestionNumber < 10:
    QuestionNumber=QuestionNumber+1
    operation = random.choice(Operations)
    print("What is", Num1 ,operation, Num2)
    guess=int(input("What is the answer to this question?"))

    if operation =="+":
        answer=Num1+Num2

    elif operation =="-":
            answer=Num1-Num2

    elif operation =="x":
        answer=Num1*Num2

    if guess==answer:
        print ("Correct")

    else:
        print("Incorrect")
```

Keep track of what the current operation is and use that value to compare